# Does MVC 4 has a built in sitemap solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was looking at ASP.NET MVC 4 and it appears that System.Web.SiteMapProvider doesn't have support for MVC features like controller and action names.

After a quick search I noticed a lot of people are creating their all provider and/or custom solution.

So it made me think: is there a reason the MVC team didn't work on a MVC Site MAP provider? Is there a more elegant way, or even a best practice to deal with menus and breadcrumbs on a large project?

I appreciate any comments.
Thanks in advance;

Comment: What is your question? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry if I made it hard to understand. Basically my question is on the post subject. But I guess the answer to that is no. As for what I'm trying to achieve it's "nothing fancy": a multi level menu and a breadcrumb using a sitemap/xml file as the data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing built-in for SiteMaps in ASP.NET MVC.

You should look at [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) which is an ASP.NET MVC SiteMapProvider implementation for ASP.NET MVC - although I dont think it has been tested with MVC 4.

MvcSiteMapProvider is based on areas, controller and action method names as opposed to fixed URL references.

Comment: i usderstood it but how to apply custom style on the ul and li which are generated?